# See and seeing with different implications

Tags: present-tense

> I am seeing my guitar teacher this Monday. (means that I have an
> appointment)

What if I do it regularly. Should it be

> I see my guitar teacher on Mondays. **OR** I am seeing my guitar
> teacher on Mondays.

Technically it should be "I see", but wouldn't it mean that I simply behold him?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between Simple Present vs. Present Progressive for expressing a habit?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130525/whats-the-difference-between-simple-present-vs-present-progressive-for-express)

Answer (score 1):

'I see', in this kind of context, means "meet with". Nobody would think you simply meant 'behold'.

However, none of these examples sound quite right. 'Seeing' someone usually means a meeting, a consultation, or something less formal like a date or a group get-together. For example, "*I see my family at weekends*". The word does not give any detail about what you might do or discuss together when you see them, and deliberately so. So, all of your statements beg the question *why are you seeing your guitar teacher*? A native speaker would be more specific:

> I have my guitar lesson on Mondays.

Comment: But, if you _do_ use 'see', the continuous tense could imply a temporary arrangement. "I'm seeing my guitar teacher on Mondays at the moment because [the usual day is inconvenient for some reason]."

Comment: There are many senses of "see". This is sense 2 in [Collins COBUILD Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see). It is quite typical for doctor's appointments. For music lessons, unless the teacher is especially salient, I agree with @Astralbee that talking about the lesson would be more typical.

Comment: Why is it not correct then  to say "Men and women see one another?" to mean they date?

Comment: @nschneid That doesn't go against my point at all. When you 'see' your doctor, you don't know the outcome. It's a consultation. You are going to tell them your symptoms and then learn what's wrong and what might happen next. If you knew what you were going for, you'd likely be more specific - "I'm having a procedure on Monday", for example.

Comment: @user1425 That's far too much of a generalisation. You can't generalise about a specific arrangement. If you are dating someone, you can say "I'm seeing them". But not every man and woman is dating.

Comment: What does "not every man and woman is dating" have to do with the issue? Sure thing, if you are dating you can sat "I am seeing them" but it's not the issue. The issue is why it is not correct to say instead of "People date one another" "People see one another"? Since you say that "See" doesn't only mean "to behold".

Comment: @user1425 Because, as you said in your original question, "seeing" *literally* means 'having sight of' something. It only means dating or having an appointment/consultation with someone in *specific contexts*, and those contexts require an arrangement. Saying "men and women see each other" is beyond that scope. It doesn't refer to an arrangement. It isn't recognisable as the idiom in question. That's why I said it is too general.